# node mysql insert and select count not working

Tags: node.js, mysql2

i'm using two function `function1`, `function2` consequetivly in `node.js`.

`function1` using to insert the data into the table.

```
for(var j=0; j < length; j++){

   connection.query('INSERT INTO TestTable SET ?', { row_name : name }, function(err, res){
      if(err) throw err;
   });
}
```

`function2` using to select the count of inserted name, count.

```
connection.query('select row_name, count(*) as count from TestTable where row_name = ?', name , function (err, rows){  
    console.log(rows);
});
```

where my `log` gives me `name : null, count : 0`

what i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, running mysql queries in a loop is a bad practice. Second,
you miss the basics of the asynchronous flow in javascript. [Here](http://www.2ality.com/2014/09/es6-promises-foundations.html) is a good article where the the basic concepts of asynchronous programming in JavaScript are explained. `connection.query` is asynchronous, so if you want your code to work, you should run counting query in the callback of the insert query on last iteration.

But as I already mentioned, it is a bad practice to run them in a loop. I would advice you only to build query string in a loop for multiple inserts, but run it only once in the end (with a counting query in the callback).